# IPA processing failed' / xcode crashes while distributing enterprise build in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, ipa, xcode10, xcode11

I was trying to `archive` and upload as `enterprise` build in the organiser. But after uncheck of `Bitcode section` the whole `Xcode 11` crashes and in another system, the organizer shows as error *'IPA processing failed'*.

I have two frameworks in my project, one has `i386, x86_64, armv7, armv7s, arm64` and other has `x86_64, armv7, arm64` architectures inside it.

I manually removed `i386, x86_64` these both architecture using `lipo`. But still, it crashes after selecting through enterprise build.

*Only one option works:* Which is when I create an archive in `Xcode 11` and prepare to build from `Xcode 10 organizer`.I can able to get `IPA file` with `enterprise` build.

Any solution on how to make an `archive` and `build` both in `Xcode 11`? Thanks!